# What was the first language library to include a GUI grid component?

Tags: gui

I was first exposed to GUI libraries in the 80's, and all of them initially included typical GUI objects like buttons, checkboxes, edit fields, and so on, but I don't recall being able to write a program that included a GUI library with a pre-built spreadsheet-like grid component until I first saw Visual Basic.

What was the first language library to actually include a GUI grid component?

Comment: If you're not necessarily tied to the idea of 'libraries', dBase 2 had a built-in BROWSE command, and apparently dates to 1981 (I first used it in 1987, not sure whether the 1981 version had BROWSE or not).

Comment: Although, now that I think back some more, the dBase2 and FoxBase+ BROWSE command wasn't well-suited for programmatic usage; we wrote our own equivalent.  It wasn't until the enhanced version in FoxPro (ca 1989) that we could use it meaningfully inside programs.  Not sure when dBase got the same, probably dBase IV.

Comment: I haven't used the List Manager in the classic Macintosh OS, but I think it was part of the original 1984 OS and remember reading a column of advice in how to right good programs, and along with "The Text Manager is not a word processor" and "The Resource Manager is not a database", was "The List Manager is not a spreadsheet".

Comment: Might be able to find ads in old Byte or other magazines for libraries with grid-type widgets.

Comment: The Xerox Star (1981) was the first commercial system to have a large collection of widgets. Likely a SmallTalk grid or table widget in there.

Comment: Anybody know when MIT Lisp machines first got a GUI?

Answer (score 3):

One candidate is the [form widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20100620005332/http://linuxjunkies.org/programming/GUI/xwindow/x11/composite.html) in the [Project Athena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Athena) Xaw library.

I couldn't find an exact date for this library; Project Athena started in 1983.

And it's really a for graphical UI, not a text-based one like dBase.

Comment: @StephenKitt much later.